# NUnit3 using the same test data across tests with different categories

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am having trouble with NUnit3 using the C# implementation wherein the test runner seems to use the same data across supposed multiple tests when I run multiple at a time. How do I fix my code to prevent it from doing this?

My tests get populated via a text file. I currently use a single "category" but will have 2 or 3 test data using the same category. I have tried assigning the test category on both fixture level and test level, but I still get the same result.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
        public static string user = "";

        [Test, TestCaseSource("Source1")]
        [Category("test")]
        public void TestSample
        {
            //do something 
        }
}
```

```
    public static List<Setup> Source1()
    {
        TestCase = IniFile.LoadBySeparator<Setup>("test.txt");
        TestCase = TestCase.Where(x = > x.category.ToLower() == "test1").ToList();
        return TestCase;        
    }
```

From the text file

```
category[===]test1
testcase_name[===]Test 1
user[===]aaaa

category[===]test1
testcase_name[===]Test 2
user[===]bbbb
```

Given the code sample above, I would expect that TestSample would be run twice, using 2 test users aaaa and bbbb. When I run the tests individually, they each use the correct test user, but when running them all one after the other (as is the case of an Azure build or a select all in Nunit GUI), Test 2 ends up using the data for Test 1.

Comment: Is `TestCase` an instance field?

Comment: It's a static field.

Comment: That's probably your problem then - a race condition, whereby both tests run together, and one is likely overwriting the value set by the other.